# Kotlin Map Checking a Cast to Remove Unchecked Cast

Tags: kotlin, generics, maps

I do not want to suppress warning I actually want to check the cast and remove unwanted types if it happens.  Trying to figure out best way but all examples are for lists not Maps.  This function is used by many classes and it can get data I don't want.  I only want ones that are serializable in this instance from inside this class.

```
class Controller(private val manager: Manager) {
  
    override fun onStatusUpdate(update: Map<String, *>) {
        // This is where I want to check is the value Serializable type
        manager.onStatusUpdate(update as Map<String, Serializable>)
    }
}

class Manager {
    fun onStatusUpdate(dataMap: Map<String, Serializable>) {
        dataMap.doSomething()....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
manager.onStatusUpdate(update.filterValues { it is Serializable }.mapValues { it.value as Serializable })
```

`filterValues` will remove all values of unwanted types, `mapValues` will change the type from `Map<String, Any?>` to `Map<String, Serializable>`, making compiler happy.

Comment: Okay what I think I was looking for...I'll write a test case and find out if its good.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, I'm afraid.

That's a result of [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-erasure).  Due to the way generics were added to Java back in JDK 1.5, type parameters are not included in the compiled bytecode.  This means that both a `Map<String, Serializable>` and a `Map<Int, List<Pair<String, Float>>` would be compiled (after inserting all the necessary casts) down to a simple `Map`, with no information about the key or value types.

So at runtime, they're the same, and there's no way to distinguish them.  (You could look at the contents, and discount *some* possible types; but that wouldn't help you in general, because `Map<Any?, Any?>` would always be a possibility.)

That's why the compiler warns you: it's not just that you *haven't* checked the type: it's that you *can't* check the type.

(The only way to make an unchecked cast safely would be to have some *other* way to know the type: for example, if you also stored the class names or Class objects separately.  Otherwise, there's always the risk of a ClassCastException, which you'd do well to allow for in some way.)

In your case, one workaround might be to check the contents of the map; if every value `is Serializable`, that might give the required behaviour, without needed to check the type of the map itself.

Comment: Seems such an odd thing, tell you you haven't checked the cast but yet give you no way to cast it safely.  Something as simple as map.filterIsInstanceOf().  I think the only way is to iterate to new map and check if the value object is instance of Serializable then add it.  But it would be nice to have this all inline.